# nggrid using rest call - not populating the ng-grid from the $scope

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

CREATED A PLNKR. Pls suggest changes to the plnkr
http://plnkr.co/aKbiu1QqODZTDnanhDbR

This is regarding nggrid not displaying data after the REST call.

When i use the $http post() and the success callback - In chrome debug window i can see that rest call is successful and json is logged on the console and there are no other errors in the console - but still no data is displayed on the grid/ui. There seems to be some problem in $http.post()  - (Even if i hardcode the  $scope.myData in the success() method i am unable to see the data populated on the grid/ui). I have debugged in chrome and found that there is correct data in $scope.mydata.

If I hardcode the data in  $scope.myData before the $http.post() call - i see the nggrid/ui populated and working fine. So there is no problem on the JSON or ng-grid data and columnDefs

Can the experts pls weigh in - thanks.
I have trimmed the some of the code below....

```
  function (controllers) {
        controllers.controller('nggridcontroller',
            [   '$scope',
                'RFLeftGridSummaryServicefunc', '$http',
                function ($scope, RFLeftGridSummaryServicefunc1, $http) {
                    // WORKS GOOD IF I HARDCODE this JSON in the $scope here outside the http call
                    //  $scope.myData  = [{"login":"kDavid1","propertyid":128105,"scenarioname":"Property History Default","year":"2014"............

                    var jsonString = '{"properties":[2323,2245]}';
                    $http({method: 'POST',
                        url: '/zzz/rf/properties/summary/?scenarioCreator=kDavid&scenarioName=budgetscenerio',
                        data: jsonString}).success(function (data) {
                        console.log('success ');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // DISPLAYS THE DATA FROM REST CALL
                        $scope.myData = data;
                        // DOES not work EVEN if I HARDCODE the working JSON in scope
                        //$scope.myData  = [{"login":"kDavid1","propertyid":128105,"scenarioname":"Property History Default","year":"2014"......
                    }).error(function (data) {
                        console.log('error ');
                    });

                    // NG-GRID JSON
                    $scope.gridOptionsFromController = {
                        //  here is data from scope
                        data: 'myData',
                        columnDefs: [
                            {field: 'year', displayName: 'Year-fromController'},
                            {field: 'occupancy', displayName: 'Occ'} ,
                            {field: 'rent', displayName: 'Rent'} ,
                            {field: 'revenue', width: '90', cellFilter: 'currency', displayName: 'Rev'}
                        ]............
```

JSON:

```
[{"login":"jim1","propertyid":128105,"scenarioname":"Property History Default","year":"2014","rent":824,"rentyoychg":0.0430,"revenue":2313024,"revenueyoychg":0.0473,"occupancy":0.956,"occupancyyoychg":-0.0052}]
```

HTML:

```
   <!-- Grid - using ng-grid -->
        <div ng-controller="nggridcontroller" class="gridStyle leftMid" ng-grid="gridOptionsFromController"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens b/c on the moment when you create 'gridOptions' object on the scope there is no 'myData' property(b/c async http success will be hit after) so I think you should define 'myData' property on the beginning as empty array:

```
  function (controllers) {
    controllers.controller('nggridcontroller',
        [   '$scope',
            'RFLeftGridSummaryServicefunc', '$http',
            function ($scope, RFLeftGridSummaryServicefunc1, $http) {
                // WORKS GOOD IF I HARDCODE this JSON in the $scope here outside the http call
                //  $scope.myData  = [{"login":"kDavid1","propertyid":128105,"scenarioname":"Property History Default","year":"2014"............

                var jsonString = '{"properties":[2323,2245]}';
                $scope.myData = [];
                $http({method: 'POST',
                    url: '/ysconfig/rf/properties/summary/?scenarioCreator=kDavid&scenarioName=budgetscenerio',
                    data: jsonString}).success(function (data) {
                    console.log('success ');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // DISPLAYS THE DATA FROM REST CALL
                    $scope.myData = data;
                    // DOES not work EVEN if I HARDCODE the working JSON in scope
                    //$scope.myData  = [{"login":"kDavid1","propertyid":128105,"scenarioname":"Property History Default","year":"2014"......
                }).error(function (data) {
                    console.log('error ');
                });

                // NG-GRID JSON
                $scope.gridOptionsFromController = {
                    //  here is data from scope
                    data: 'myData',
                    //  here is the dynamic template for a ROW - and not just html header - it has data for year etc.
                    // columndefs is a misnomer - this has the entire ROW of data here.
                    columnDefs: [
                        {field: 'year', displayName: 'Year-fromController'},
                        {field: 'occupancy', displayName: 'Occ'} ,
                        {field: 'rent', displayName: 'Rent'} ,
                        {field: 'revenue', width: '90', cellFilter: 'currency', displayName: 'Rev'}
                    ]............
```

Comment: tried declaring $scope.myData = [] outside - no luck. Still does not display the data.

Comment: i inspected the $scope using ng-inspector /batarang plugin and there is data in $scope.mydata. However renderedRows in nggrid internal structure is empty array - not sure why ??

Comment: Maybe you need run $scope.$apply().

Comment: The solution is that in the HTML code -  ng-grid options and the controller need to be in different divs. I had it in one DIV- that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/59)

```
$scope.myData =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), $scope.myData );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @TheLittlePig I agree with you, but since I am a newbie to Angular I am not sure why it works. But doing certailny solved my issue. But i guess Angualr is not able to parse the json string properly.